# How to retain values in textboxes even after navigating to another page in a jquery mobile application

Tags: jquery, session, textbox, state, retain

There is a jquery mobile application that I am working on which targets Android, iOS, Windows and Blackberry platforms. I am using Jquery mobile 1.3.1 with Jquery 1.9 wrapped in phonegap.

The requirement is :- I have an HTML page with 2 input fields, a number field and a button. On "click" of the button I have to navigate to another page with a "Back" button in it. When the page navigates back to the first page, I will have to retain all the values that the user entered on that first page.

What's happening now is that when I navigate back, the values the user entered are not retained i.e that is the "state" of the page is not retained.

Is there a way to possibly retain the values/state of the page without using session storage ?

Answer (score 0):

I think LocalStorage might well solve this problem for you.

[Heres a nice tuorial](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The data I will be saving are secure information. I was wondering if there are any plugins available to probably save the state of the views.